append current time with setDate in angular
I'm getting date in this format from backend

2024-05-31
in maxfrom variable

this.maxFromDate = new Date(x.response.Date);
this.maxFromDate.setDate(this.maxFromDate.getDate());

this way it returns Fri May 31 2024 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) this format
this.StartDate = this.datePipe.transform(
            this.maxFromDate,
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          );

but instead of 5:30 i want current time to be appended

you can just use setHours method with a Date object set to the currentDate
// get the currentDate
const currentDate = new Date();

//update the date with currentTime
this.maxFromDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours(), currentDate.getMinutes(), currentDate.getSeconds());

Here is a working sample


const currentDate = new Date();

const oneOtherDate = new Date("2024-05-27T08:00:00"); 
oneOtherDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours(), currentDate.getMinutes(), currentDate.getSeconds());

console.log(oneOtherDate);



